# Getting 401 error while using rest services of IBM watson in dart as post method

Tags: authentication, post, dart, flutter, ibm-watson

this is the fist time i've tried post method in dartLang.
ive used a simple rest api , where you have to post some string(text) and will get Json as response.
I've also Given right Username and password, yet the response I recieve Finally is {code: 401, error: Unauthorized}.

May I know Where I am goin wrong?? I've never worked with Rest api's post in DartLang.

Here is its simple documentation https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/personality-insights/api/v3/curl.html?curl

```
import 'package:untitled1/untitled1.dart' as untitled1;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';


void main() async {

 Map hello;
 hello= await getjson();
 print(hello);

}



 Future<Map> getjson() async {
  String data;
 data= """ Insert Random long text """;



  var url = 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality- 
 insights/api/v3/profile?username=6cfcbb79-1801-4588-a1b3- 
  5c3ec101244f&password=YFM6h0rIFfzf';
     http.Response response= await http.post(url, body: data, headers: 
 {"accept" : "application/json","Content-Type": "text/plain"},);
   return json.decode(response.body);


     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Watson reference that you provide shows an example with `curl -u`. `curl` defaults to `Basic` authentication when `-u` is provided without a specific authentication method (e.g. digest). So, adding the username and password to the url is not the same.

Dart's http client supports basic authentication, but will require an additional round-trip to the server, so it's often simpler to send the credentials with every request. The following code gets you past the 401 error.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

main() async {
  http.Response r = await http.post(
    'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile',
    body: 'some random string',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': basicAuthorizationHeader(
        '6cfcbb79-1801-4588-a1b3-5c3ec101244f',
        'YFM6h0rIFfzf',
      )
    },
  );
  print(r.statusCode);
  print(r.body);
}

String basicAuthorizationHeader(String username, String password) {
  return 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
}
```